# Download crosstab(tableau report) from tableau online and stored to aws s3 bucket by using any script

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop, tableau-cloud

Can you please help me to Download Tableau report(Cross tab) from Tableau online and save it in AWS S3 Bucket by using any script.
Currently I have batch script, in this script using TABCMD command for download cross tab from tableau online to Network drive location, but we are not going to use Network drive location, instead of network drive location we will use AWS S3 bucket location. So can any one please help me on this.

[Sample Report image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L967G.png)

Comment: You need to build some code and ask specific questions about what the cause of any error might be. Look into tableauserverclient and boto3 python libraries if tabcmd isn't doing everything for you.